# insert the string & display the character of that string in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Write a function to insert the string in a table which will display the character of string like if we pass (KRISHNA  it will display

K

R

I

S

H

N

A
)        Inside the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (source_string varchar2(20), target_string varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_string in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    insert into test (source_string, target_string)
  4    select par_string,
  5           regexp_replace(par_string, '(.)', '\1' ||chr(10))
  6    from dual;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test ('KRISHNA');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

SOURCE_STRING        TARGET_STRING
-------------------- --------------------
KRISHNA              K
                     R
                     I
                     S
                     H
                     N
                     A


SQL>
```

---

If it has to be a function, then - as you see *how* to do it - you could have switched to it (the function) yourself, instead of insisting on someone else doing your homework.

Anyway:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_string in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return regexp_replace(par_string, '(.)', '\1' ||chr(10));
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> insert into test (source_string, target_string)
  2  values ('IHCASAYBAS', f_test ('IHCASAYBAS'));

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

SOURCE_STRING        TARGET_STRING
-------------------- --------------------
KRISHNA              K
                     R
                     I
                     S
                     H
                     N
                     A

IHCASAYBAS           I
                     H
                     C
                     A
                     S
                     A
                     Y
                     B
                     A
                     S


SQL>
```

Comment: it ask for function not for procedure

Comment: Does it? Why didn't you switch to a function yourself, then? See edited answer.